# Mimicing the Linux device model with regular files in userspace

Tags: python, linux, ipc

I would like to represent a state of a daemon through a directory structure with files. The daemon is responsible for providing a shell interface to controlling sensors. Something similar to how the Linux device model or the GPIO console interface is implemented, just with plain files, written in Python in userspace :).

Example:

Daemon runs and creates the directory structure listing the available sensors. Example of how the directory structure might look:

```
sensors
`-- sensor1
    `-- sensor-ouput
```

`sensor-ouput` is just a plain file which serves as abstraction for the current sensor value.

Here is the code for creating the example structure:

```
import time,os

    if not os.path.exists('sensors/sensor1'):
        os.makedirs('sensors/sensor1')
    f = open('sensors/sensor1/sensor-ouput','w+')
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(str(i))
        f.flush()
    f.close()
```

Questions:

- Why can I write to the file while the daemon is running? `echo 1 > sensor-ouput` doesn't give an error.
- There is only a single process writing to the file and potentially multiple reading it at the same time. Are there some synchronisation issues  that I'm missing in these scenario?
- Given that the file is opened on a ramfs partition, does this approach lag behind using named pipes?

Comment: Because you can't do what the kernel can do. Absolutely; the kernel never actually writes files. Named pipes are the solution to a completely different problem.

Comment: `kernel never actually writes files` if I write them to a ram, neither will they be in this solution

Comment: If you write a file to a ramdisk you are still writing a file.

Comment: IMO a way better approach would be to do as the kernel do, i.e. create a virtual file system; with fuse it's quite easy to do. Instead of continously writing (potentially useless) stuff to files (also exposing yourself to race conditions and the like), fuse calls your functions when other applications try to read (or perform other operations) on the "fake files" you expose.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to a file because files are not locked by default. You need to lock it with os.lockf().

Your multiple readers might read different values where you expect the same. Consider the following scenario

```
writer writes 10
reader #1 reads 10
reader #2 reads 10
writer writes 11
reader #3 reads 11
```

at this point reader #3 is in a different state compared to readers #1 and #2.

Named pipes are FIFO structures They insure the order of messages where a file does not. On the other hand, pipes are not persistent, once the message is read it disappears.

Edit: actually fcntl.flock() is probably what you want for locking, not os.lockf()